# Html.DisplayFor doesn't return value on submit using it in mvc 4 Razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I pass some dummy data to my View just to have something to work with :

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Create table";
            var model = new List<Auction>();
            model.Add(new Auction
            {
                Title = "First Title",
                Description = "First Description"
            });
            model.Add(new Auction
            {
                Title = "Second Title",
                Description = "Second Description"
            });
            model.Add(new Auction
            {
                Title = "Third Title",
                Description = "Third Description"
            });
            model.Add(new Auction
            {
                Title = "Fourht Title",
                Description = "Fourth Description"
            });

            return View(model);
        }
```

I display this in my view :

```
@model List<Ebuy.Website.Models.Auction>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <table border="1" >
        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
        {
            <tr>

                <td>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x[i].Id)
                    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].Title)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(x => x[i].Description)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>

    <button type="submit">Save</button>
}
```

and now I want to make some manipulation of the submitted data :

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(List<Auction> model)
        {
            var test = model;
            model[1].Title = "Test";
            return View(model);
        }
```

But when I debug this I see that the `Description` properties are send back but the `Title` properties don't have value. As you can see above I display them with `@Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].Title)`. Is this some default behaviour or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`@Html.DisplayFor` doesn't output an input field (or any form field for that matter) so it isn't part of the values the form posts.

If you want the title posted as part of the form you may want to add an additional

`@Html.HiddenFor(x => x[i].Title)`

Comment: Thanks. Maybe there is really no need to keep track of the read only values. Gonna rethink what I want. But good to know how `@Html.DisplayFor` works.